# How to mutate values of nested structs in Rust?

Tags: rust

I'm having trouble figuring out how to mutate nested structs. I have a `Folder` struct that can hold `File`s and other `Folder`s inside it. I then want to be able to add new files and folders to those nested folders after creating them, but I keep running into errors.

Code:

```rust
type SubFolder = Vec<Box<Folder>>; 
type Files = Vec<String>;

#[derive(Debug)] 
struct Folder { 
    files: Files, 
    sub_folder: SubFolder 
}

impl Folder { 
    pub fn new() -> Self { 
        Self { 
            files: Vec::new(), 
            sub_folder: Vec::new(), 
        } 
    }

    pub fn add_file(&mut self, file: String) {
        self.files.push(file);
    }

    pub fn add_folder(&mut self, dir: Box<Folder>) {
        self.sub_folder.push(dir);
    }
}

fn main() { 
    let mut folder_1 = Folder::new(); 
    let mut folder_2 = Folder::new();

    folder_1.add_folder(Box::new(folder_2));
    folder_2.add_file(String::from("b.txt")); // Error

}
```

Error Message:

```rust
error[E0382]: borrow of moved value: `folder_2`
  --> src/main.rs:32:5
   |
29 |     let mut folder_2 = Folder::new();
   |         ------------ move occurs because `folder_2` has type `Folder`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
30 |
31 |     folder_1.add_folder(Box::new(folder_2));
   |                                  -------- value moved here
32 |     folder_2.add_file(String::from("b.txt")); // Error
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ value borrowed here after move
```

Is it even possible to do this? Or do I need to use unsafe code? Any resources or suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Suggest reading: [Learn Rust With Entirely Too Many Linked Lists](https://rust-unofficial.github.io/too-many-lists/).  The error message has explained itself well: you have moved `folder_2` already. IMHO, `Box` is not the right pointer here, you may need referece or `Rc`.

Comment: PS: If you're doing Advent of Code 2022, Day 7, think hard about whether you actually need to build up that tree structure to answer the question ;-)

Comment: lol Yeah this did came from that, but this doesn't try to solve that problem. I was just curious on how you would go about on implementing a simple file system like that with structs in Rust.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for your methods `add_folder` and `add_file` you need mut reference to self. However after folder2 has been moved you can not reference it anymore.

There are a few ways to address it.

1. You can use "full path".

Like so:

```
type SubFolder = Vec<Box<Folder>>;
type Files = Vec<String>;
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Folder {
    files: Files,
    sub_folder: SubFolder
}

impl Folder {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        Self {
            files: Vec::new(),
            sub_folder: Vec::new(),
        }
    }

    pub fn add_file(&mut self, file: String) {
        self.files.push(file);
    }

    pub fn add_folder(&mut self, dir: Box<Folder>) {
        self.sub_folder.push(dir);
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut folder_1 = Folder::new();
    let mut folder_2 = Folder::new();

    folder_1.add_folder(Box::new(folder_2));
    folder_1.sub_folder[0].add_file(String::from("b.txt")); // Ok
}
```

2. Or if you really need to reference folder2 then you have to own it multiple times, so you need Rc for multiple ownership and RefCell for interior mutability as Rc is read only

E.g.:

```
use std::cell::RefCell;
use std::rc::Rc;

type SubFolder = Vec<Rc<RefCell<Folder>>>;
type Files = Vec<String>;
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Folder {
    files: Files,
    sub_folder: SubFolder
}

impl Folder {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        Self {
            files: Vec::new(),
            sub_folder: Vec::new()
        }
    }

    pub fn add_file(&mut self, file: String) {
        self.files.push(file);
    }

    pub fn add_folder(&mut self, dir: Rc<RefCell<Folder>>) {
        self.sub_folder.push(dir);
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut folder_1 = Folder::new();
    let mut folder_2 = Rc::new((RefCell::new(Folder::new())));

    folder_1.add_folder(Rc::clone(folder_2));
    folder_2.borrow_mut().add_file(String::from("b.txt")); // Ok
}
```

Btw, with Vec you can not address subfolder or file by name. Maybe better use Hashmap?

Comment: Thank you, this works! I've read that you shouldn't rely on `clone` to satisfy the borrow checker. Is `Rc` a case where using `clone` is ok?

Comment: Clone is not really "cloning" anything in case of Rc. Only creates one more link. So it's cheap. What you are referring to is that you can usually trick borrow checker by cloning, this is a bad practice in general. Rc has some overhead though. E.g it is allocating on the heap vs stack

Comment: Note that if `Folder` implemented `Clone`, then `folder_2.clone()` would clone the folder and not the `Rc`! For this reason, it is considered good practice to use `Rc::clone (folder_2)` when you want to clone the `Rc`.

Comment: Damn, I knew it and forgot again, I'll amend, thank you!